# How to convert a byte array to a String in Java, and skip all null bytes?

Tags: java, arrays, string

I have a byte array that's contains a string at the end of the array, and the beginning of the array is padded with zeroes. I'm using the following code to convert it to a string:

```
String myText = new String(byteArray, "UTF-8");
```

However, I'm getting a bunch of weird characters prepended to the string, due to the 0 padding. How do I get rid of it?

Thanks.

Comment: Just look through the array to find where you start getting non-zero bytes, then call the constructor overload that allows you to specify the part of the array to convert? Have you tried that yet?

Comment: @user1118764 Hey Did you find any solution for this. In my case null bytes could be in any place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`String(byte[], int, int, String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String(byte[],%20int,%20int,%20String)) constructor.

The first `int` is an offset through the `byte[]`: just look for the first non-zero byte; the second `int` is the number of bytes. So, call like:

```
new String(
    byteArray, firstNonNullByte, byteArray.length - firstNonNullByte, "UTF-8");
```

Comment: What if I don't know how long the valid string within the String is, and hence, don't know how many zeroes are padded?

Comment: @user1118764 "I have a byte array that's contains a string at the end of the array, and the beginning of the array is padded with zeroes." If that's not the case, you've stated your problem poorly.

Comment: What I mean is, let's say my byteArray is 128 bytes. It could contain "Hello" or "Bye", or any other string up to 128 characters. I do not know what the string is in advance. I guess I could loop through the byteArray and figure out the index to the first non-zero character, is that what you mean?

Comment: Well, yes. To find the first non-zero byte, loop through until you find a non-zero byte.

Answer (score 0):

You could use apache org.apache.commons.lang3.ArrayUtils.

```
int firstNonNullByte = ArrayUtils.lastIndexOf(byteArray, 0) + 1;
```

Comment: The null bytes are at the start, not the end.

Comment: What if the array ends with `\0`?

Comment: it wasn't specified. What if array has 0 in the middle?

Comment: Indeed, another problem with using `lastIndexOf`. The question states "the beginning of the array is padded with zeroes", these are the ones you need to get rid of.

Comment: + "I have a byte array that's contains a string at the end of the array". I don't see any issues with zeros at the beginning and sting at the end. In another case you should just compress array by removing all the zeros.

Comment: So, if you've got zeros at the start and the end of the string, how does `lastIndexOf` help you remove *both*?

Comment: to answer your question - you have to iterate from beginning and from the end until you reach string. You'll get first and last indexes. But in this cate there is "sting at the end". No zeros!

Answer (score 0):

I would try to remove the leading zeroes and then just use the remaining part of the `byte` array that is useful:

```
public class Test {

 public static byte[] removeZeroes(byte[] data) {
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        if(data[i] != '\0') {
            break;
        }
    }
    return Arrays.copyOfRange(data, i, data.length);
}

public static void main(String args[]) {
    byte[] byteArray = new byte[10];
    byteArray[0] = '\0';
    byteArray[1] = '\0';
    byteArray[2] = '\0';
    byteArray[3] = '\0';
    byteArray[4] = 's';
    byteArray[5] = 't';
    byteArray[6] = 'r';
    byteArray[7] = 'i';
    byteArray[8] = 'n';
    byteArray[9] = 'g';
    byteArray = removeZeroes(byteArray);

    try {
        String myText = new String(byteArray, "UTF-8");
        System.out.println(myText);
    }
    catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Comment: I think the OP means the `byte` array is padded with 0 rather than '0' (i.e. byte value of 48).

Answer (score 0):

My solution would be to remove zeros from the beginning of the array:

```
public byte[] trim(byte[] bytes) {
        int i = 0;
        while (i<bytes.length && bytes[i] == 0) {
            i++;
        }

        return Arrays.copyOfRange(bytes, i, bytes.length);        
 }
```

Comment: Aside from the fact that copying the array is unnecessary, this code is broken (it might fail with an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException).

Comment: @AndyTurner ok. There was a bug but I fixed it. And yes, copying the array is not unnecessary but it can be useful when you want to do some additional operations on it after converting to string. of course it depends on needs

Answer (score 0):

No need to loop to find where the padding ends, you can fix the string using regex. Index juggling with loops is dangerous, because it would a perfect place to introduce by-one error one day.

```
String myText = (new String(byteArray, "UTF-8")).replaceAll("^\\x00*", "");
```

Regex means:

- at the beginning of string (`^`)
- character with hexadecimal code 0 (`\x00`, and `\` should be escaped in java, so `\\x00`)
- zero or more times (`*`)